# Playing With Friends On Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have got a Single Player World that I want my friend to play with me on. However we aren't in the same LAN, how do we play together?

Answer (score -4):

Open your resource pack, click resource pack folder, click .minecraft on the file path.
There should be a list of files over there, click on the file named saves. FULL PATH:
C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves
Copy the world file that should be named after your world, and apply it to your server.